# Are $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{H}$ the only continuous number systems over $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ respectively?

Tags: complex-numbers, metric-spaces, quaternions, number-systems

When I say $\mathbb{C}$ is a number system over $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, I mean that the field of complex numbers is identified with the set of dilative rotations of the affine real plane ($\mathbb{R}^{2}$) characterized by the Pythagorean metric.  When I say $\mathbb{H}$ is a number system over $\mathbb{R}^{4}$, I mean that the skew-field of quaterions is identified with the set of dilative Hermitian rotations over the affine complex plane $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ characterized by the Hermitian metric.  When I say these are continuous, I mean that they inherit the continuum properties of the real numbers.

It occurs to me that Minkowski space is a geometry over $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ characterized by the Minkowski metric.  But the continuum of spacetime events does not appear to constitute a number system.  Unlike the complex numbers and the quaternions, the Lorentz transformations and space points (spacetime events) are "decoupled".

So I ask, is there some theorem or uncontradicted proposition that says the only continuous number systems expressible as ordered pairs and ordered quadruples of real numbers are the complex numbers and quaternions, respectively?

Comment: See the [Cayley-Dickson construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley–Dickson_construction).

Comment: So, I guess the answer is:No. There are, in fact counter examples.  However... the counterexamples appear to be variants of the aforementioned number systems (or algebras).

Comment: If looking at unital associative real algebras without zero-divisors, then $\mathbb{C}$ is the only one of dimension $2$ and $\mathbb{H}$ should be the only one of dimension $4$ (look at $\mathbb{R}[z]$ and the minimal polynomial $f$ of $z$ for various non-real elements $z$ in the algebra, $\mathbb{R}[z]\cong \mathbb{R}[X]/(f(X))$ is commutative with no zeros divisors so it is $\cong \mathbb{C}$, then massage it to obtain the algbera of dimension $4$ must be $\mathbb{C}+j\mathbb{C}$ with $jz = \overline{z} j$)

Comment: Would you regard the octonions as a "continuous number system"? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonion

Comment: The geometric properties of $\Bbb C$ and $\Bbb H$ you mention are related to their construction via https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_algebra . In general, Clifford algebras have zero divisors.

Comment: To add to my previous comment, indefinite quadratic forms such as the Lorentzian form defining the Minkowski metric, can be used to construct Clifford algebras too.

Comment: By "hermitian rotations" do you mean unitary matrices? Because when you turn a quaternion into a $2\times 2$ complex matrix, you get a unitary matrix (up to scaling), not a hermitian matrix.

Comment: All terms are complex:

$$\mathfrak{z}_{\bar{1}}=\alpha\mathfrak{z}_{1}+\gamma\mathfrak{z}_{2};$$

$$\mathfrak{z}_{\bar{2}}=\beta\mathfrak{z}_{1}+\delta\mathfrak{z}_{2};$$

Comment: How did no one mention the $2 \times 2$ matrices over $\mathbb R$?  I suggest the OP look at the notions of rings, fields and algebras.

Comment: @Kimball The set of orthogonal rotations ($2\times{2}$ matrices) scaled by real numbers is the set of dilative rotations of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with a Pythagorean metric.  That is identical to the complex numbers.  In fact it is one way of defining $\mathbb{C}$.  I don't believe the set of all $2\times{2}$ matrices with real number elements constitutes a "number system".  I don't have a precise definition of *number system*, but, at a minimum, it should subsume those constructs we have already agreed to call number systems of which it is an extension.

Comment: I mean the full matrix ring $M_2(\mathbb R)$, and I am suggesting that by number system you should mean something like a _ring_, and if you want, you can assume something like it is a finite-dimensional $\mathbb R$-vector space, i.e., a finite-dimensional _algebra_ over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Kimball that was largely my point in asking.  Minkowski space is a finite dimensional vector space, but dosn't appear to qualify as a number system.  The skew field of quaternions is also 4-dimensional vector space, and it is considered a number system.